# How to create this soft look around the logo?

Tags: logo

Any ideas of how to create such looking logo like this:

[image: Logo image]

This logo in [site](http://designerthemes.com/).

I like this roundness feel around letters. Dribble logo is also with similar effect.

I do not think that it is only shadow (if its shadow at all).

Comment: The similarities between the two logos is that they both use a hand-drawn script face. To create a logo like that, hand-write your company name in cursive and/or purchase/find a script typeface you like.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it's just a nice typeface to me. I don't see any treatment actually applied to it besides the white fill.

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing is anti-aliasing of the curved shapes combined with a bit of artifacting because the image is an 8-bit PNG. It looks a little fuzzy, in other words, because it *is* a little fuzzy. There is no glow or shadow applied to give that effect.

Answer (score 1):

I am agree with mike,
but if you want to create manually you have to really work hard on illustrator, and the good news is,  its a font named [Wendy LP](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/wendy-lp/) you can use it.

and you can download [dribbble logo vector file here](http://dribbble.com/site/brand) see if it can help...

Answer (score 1):

Font Squirrel has a very similar face (it's free too for screen). It's not 100% exact, but I'm betting it's the bastard child of Adobe®'s (not so free) font. You could create the logo in Illustrator and convert it to paths with some minor tweaks to a couple of the characters.

Pacifico => http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/pacifico

Sorry...to the "fuzz factor" - I think that's the effect of converting a very smooth sans-serif to a white graphic (causing anti-aliasing on the edges - like Alan said) and applying it to a black background. I don't think there's a blur or softening technique used at all.